# Python base32 decode result is different

Tags: python

This question may sound stupid, but it had troubled me for days.

Basically, I used `base64_b32decode()` to decode a base32 (RFC 3548 / RFC4648) key in python.

The result is `` b'\x07\xe7\xabN\xe9\x15k\xb9\x1eC\x0eR\x1a\xd3\xcd\xb09` F' ``

However, when I used [this website](https://cryptii.com/) to decode the key.

The website's result is `07 e7 ab 4e e9 15 6b b9 1e 43 0e 52 1a d3 cd b0 39 60 20 46`.

The problem is I don't know why does python returned 'ab**N**' when the website showed 'ab'. Mind the additional `N` in the string.

I mean ... why does python returned extra characters and also it seems to me that there are still `b0 39 60 20 46` byte missing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Python Code:

```
import base64

key = "A7T2WTXJCVV3SHSDBZJBVU6NWA4WAICG"

print(base64.b32decode(key))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those strings are identical.  The value of the ASCII character N is 0x4E, and the last for (0x39 0x60 0x20 0x46) are "9" "space" "space" "F".  When Python prints a byte string, it prints all normal characters as normal characters, and the non-printable characters show up as hex escapes.  Use

```
import codecs
print(codecs.encode(bstr,'hex'))
```

to see that.  The `binascii` module also has methods to convert to hex strings.

Answer (score 3):

The `N` appears here:

```
ab   4e e9   # website
\xab N  \xe9 # python
```

and is caused only by different output formats. Hex code `4E` belongs to ASCII letter `N`.